# Update a view on a schedule

Tags: android

I am trying to update my view but a I have a bit problem

I take data from Internet and I want to update the same view with new data every minute.

What is the best way to do this.

As it stands I'm currently trying this timer at the end of my view:

```
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

        private void TimerMethod() {
              Csv csv= new Csv(simbol);
              csv.readCSV();
              ArrayList<Quotes> info = new ArrayList<Quotes>();
              info= csv.getListaQuotes();

              Intent i =  new Intent(getParent(), TabGrupo1.class).putExtra("opc", 2);
              i.putExtra("datos", info);
              TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
              parentActivity.startChildActivity("Component", i);

        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

but I obtain this error

```
07-14 13:23:00.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(911): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
07-14 13:23:00.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.finance/com.finance.TabGrupo1}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
07-14 13:23:00.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-14 13:23:00.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
07-14 13:23:00.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(911):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
07-14 13:23:00.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(911):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
07-14 13:23:00.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(911):     at com.finance.TabGroupActivity.startChildActivity(TabGroupActivity.java:57)
07-14 13:23:00.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(911):     at com.finance.Info$1.TimerMethod(Info.java:67)
```

My Activity is a Group of Activity because I use Tab and show the view in different tab.
In this case I want to refresh tab 2, that the same view that is running.

Any ideas or suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Which line above corresponds to: 07-14 13:23:00.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(911):     at com.finance.Info$1.TimerMethod(Info.java:67)

Comment: this line                    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in Android.
In [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) mainly three methods 
1.onPreexecute()
2.doInBackground()
3.onPost()
Refer this  Using this you can easily found your solution

Comment: Did you try to include a link? If so it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something that could be solved with a Content Provider, Broadcast Receiver, and Service with an alarm. 
Set the service to run every min with Alarm Manager. Have the service get the new data and sends a broadcast informing the main Activity that there is new information to display. 
An amazingly good video tutorial on Broadcast Receivers can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/user/MarakanaTechTV#p/c/E953C0B85B50AB62/1/3yt506_MBmU).

Additionally, the rest of his bootcamp videos piece together a program with very similar functionality.